# не получается проимпортировать pywin32 (win32gui,win32api) в проект pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, импорт, pywin32

Windows10 64-bit, python 3.6 64-bit,
Пробовал ставить pywin32 (32  и 64 bit) и с exe и с pip whl -- не помогло
Pycharm подчеркивает строку import win32gui красным, и пишет no module named win32gui, однако в выпадающем списке автодополнения после ввода слова import win32gui предлагает

Comment: А если добавить полный путь до модуля? 
`from os.path import dirname;
sys.path.append(dirname(__file__))`

Answer (score -1):

Было примерно такое,нужно установить python 3.7.4,мне это помогло